# Xcode 6.1: iPhone 5s simulator returns blank screen

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios-simulator, xcode6

My app runs normally on the iPhone 4s and iPhone 5 simulators, but anything above that such as the iPhone 5s, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus simulators all return a blank white screen.

It's strange because it isn't coherent. I thought at first it was a problem with iOS 8 compatibility, but it isn't. It runs perfectly fine on the iOS 8 run iPhone 5 and iPhone 4s simulators.

So I checked my storyboard, and looked at the initial view controller. The initial view controller resembles the blank screen. It seems as though, the view controller is not loading in the storyboard.

I've also tried removing/adding new simulators but that also doesn't seem to work.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? Is it coherent with the latest simulators? Or is it a problem with storyboarding?

**UPDATE:**

Following @Jeev's suggestion, I added a launch image. It still didn't work, but I looked in the console and caught this message:

> Xcode[49653]: : failed to acquire
>   service transport reservation: Error Domain=DYAMDErrorDomain
>   Code=-402653150 "The service is invalid."

Comment: Have you tried with resetting the simulator? `iOS Simulator menu -> Reset Content and Settings...`

Comment: @AsifAsif Yes, to no avail.

Comment: @YashwantChauhan you started making the app on which Xcode? 5 or 6?

Comment: @YashwantChauhan have you added the Launch Images for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus? If not, Please add Launch Image for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus, then Check and let us know

Comment: @YashwantChauhan hmm, sorry bro am seeing this error first time. I thought Adding the splash screens should solve the Problem. Please let me know when you find some Solution. Last thing you can do is, try the Same project on Some other Machine.

Comment: Huh. The problem was that the app was stuck in a loading phase. I was loading data into a UICollectionView, and it went into an infinite loop. It kept on adding data and didn't stop. However it's strange that it's only coherent with the iPhone 6 and 6+ simulators. It loads everything quickly in the older simulators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was that the app was stuck in a loading phase. I was loading data into a UICollectionView, and it went into an infinite loop. It kept on adding data and didn't stop. However it's strange that it's only coherent with the iPhone 6 and 6+ simulators. It loads everything quickly in the older simulators.

Comment: how did you discover the app got stuck in a loading phase?